# How to print the filename with respect to content inside in python

Tags: python, file, file-io, os.walk

I have 2 files `a.txt` and `b.txt`

`a.txt` contains text "T Mobile rider" with 2 blank lines.
`b.txt` contains 2 blank lines followed by text "Iphone".

code

```
import os
for (dirname,dirs,files) in os.walk('.'):
for filename in files:
    if filename.endswith('.txt'):
        thefile = os.path.join(dirname,filename)
        size =  (os.path.getsize(thefile),thefile)
        if size[0] == 22 or size[0] == 23:
            print ('T-Mobile:',thefile)
            continue
        fhand = open(thefile,'r')
        lines = list()
        for line in fhand:
            lines.append(line)
            #print (lines)
        fhand.close()
        if len(lines) == 3 and lines[2].startswith('Iphone'):
            print ('iPhone:', thefile)
            continue
```

My output

```
T-Mobile: .\Captures\a.txt
T-Mobile: .\Captures\b.txt
```

Desired output

```
T-Mobile: .\Captures\a.txt
iPhone: .\Captures\b.txt
```

Comment: Question is not very clear. Please post the contents of text files. Also, I see so many magic numbers and hard-codes in the code, not looking pretty logic to be honest.

Comment: unrelated: just do `lines = list(fhand)` instead of your loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have printed the filename in following logic:

- `iPhone: FILENAME` if the file contains `Iphone` in any of the lines.
- `T-Mobile: FILENAME` if the file contains `T Mobile` in any of the lines.

Folder structure:

```
├── Captures
│   ├── a.txt
│   └── b.txt
└── code.py
```

Code:

```
import os
for dirname, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            thefile = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
            with open(thefile) as f:
                lines = f.readlines()
                if any('Iphone' in line for line in lines):
                    print('iPhone:', thefile)
                if any('T Mobile' in line for line in lines):
                    print('T-Mobile:', thefile)
```

Output:

```
T-Mobile: ./Captures/a.txt
iPhone: ./Captures/b.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I recreated your case on my computer and found *a kind of* solution you might want:

```py
import os
import re

for (dirname, dirs, files) in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.endswith('.txt'):
            thefile = os.path.join(dirname, filename)
            with open(thefile, 'r') as fhand:  # open the file using with formula is preferred
                # this block is for classifying the files
                for line in fhand:
                    if re.match('t[ .-]?mobile', line.lower()):
                        print('T-Mobile: ', thefile)
                        break
                    elif re.match('iphone', line.lower()):
                        print('iPhone: ', thefile)
                        break
```

Note that I changed the way the files are classified using [re module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html). With the example you provided I believe these would actually serve better. Here I open each '.txt' file found and read it line by line, trying to find patterns that tells which group it belongs to (here there are only two - T-Mobile and iPhone, but maybe you would like to define more). File can only be classified as one group, so once the line that meet the condition is found, file is closed and appropriate message is printed.

---

The conditions I provided are way less strict then yours so they might not cover everything, producing false-positive results. Exemplary, if you have some file that starts the first line with "Iphone" it will get classified to iPhone group. If for some reason you want to only match these files that have this word in third line, then in the block that is responsible for classifying the files instead of iterating over lines you could read them all at once using fhand.readlines() and applying the conditions to specified line.

The reason I changed the logic a bit is that it is a bad practice to use hardcoded conditions that are hard to understand. Moreover these are really vulnerable for any changes and need a lot of modifications if anything happens.